# R, ifelse returns only one value

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe as below.

```
test <- data.frame (myrank = c(0.9629,0.1296), poster = c("dial","bear"))
test
##  myrank poster
## 1 0.9629   dial
## 2 0.1296   bear
```

I have a function with ifelse as below but it only returns one value and I cannot figure out why.

```
color <- function (x){
    x$colorchip <- ifelse((((x$myrank> 0) | (x$myrank= 0)) & x$myrank < 0.143),
                          "#FF0000",
                          ifelse((x$myrank > 0.143 & x$myrank < 0.286),
                                 "#FF1919",
                                 ifelse((x$myrank > 0.286 & x$myrank < 0.428571),
                                        "#FF3333",
                                        ifelse((x$myrank > 0.428571 & x$myrank < 0.571429),
                                               "#FFFFFF",
                                               ifelse((x$myrank > 0.571429 & x$myrank < 0.714286),
                                                      "#3333D6",
                                                      ifelse((x$myrank > 0.714286 & x$myrank < 0.857143),
                                                             "#1919D1",
                                                             "#0000CC"
                                                      ))))))
    return(x$colorchip)
}


color(test)
## [1] "#FF0000" "#FF0000"
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: have a look at `x$myrank = 0`. It should be `x$myrank == 0`. You overwrite the value. This might be the cause.

Comment: also, I think your `(myrank>0)` clause will trump everything else.  Maybe you meant `myrank<0` ?

Comment: @Ben Bolker: nope, why shoult it? there first line says:  `0<= x$myrank < 0.143`

Comment: sorry @user3116916, I misread the parentheses (it's easier to read your way)

Comment: @MarkHeckmann, thanks! I couldn't think about that!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@MarkHeckmann has identified your specific problem, but I would recommend this function instead:

```
color <- function (x){
     cols <- c("#FF0000","#FF1919","#FF3333",
               "#FFFFFF","#3333D6","#1919D1",
               "#0000CC")
     i <- findInterval(x,c(0,0.143,0.286,0.428571,0.571429,
                             0.714286,0.857143,Inf))
     cols[i]
 }
 test <- data.frame (myrank = c(0.9629,0.1296),
                     poster = c("dial","bear"))
 color(test$myrank)
 ## "#0000CC" "#FF0000"
```

Your code might be easier to read if you replaced the cutpoints with `(0:7)/7`. You might also find the `?colorRamp` function useful ...

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned alot - I was struggling with findInterval and decided to go to easier one. Also, I was able to find out library("RColorBrewer") and made a good use of it! Thanks!